# Iterate through a map of lists?

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, iterator, auto

I have a `map<string, list<int> >` which I want to iterate over the list and print out each number. I keep getting a compile error talking about conversion between a const_iterator and iterator. What am I doing wrong with this?

```
for (map<string, list<int> >::iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); it++)
{
   cout << it->first << ":";
   for (list<int>::iterator lit = it->second.begin(); lit  != it->second.end(); lit++)
      cout << " " << intToStr(*lit);
   cout << "\n";
}

error: conversion from
  ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::list<int, std::allocator<int> > > >’
to non-scalar type
  ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::list<int, std::allocator<int> > > >’
requested|
```

Comment: Is there a chance your `words` map is `const`?

Comment: Yes it's const I didn't understand since I didn't define it as const in the protected section. It became const with the function(that is const) inside the class completely forgot it was a const function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map<string, list<int> >::iterator
```

should be

```
map<string, list<int> >::const_iterator
```

Either your `map` is `const`, or your map is a member of a `class` and you're calling this code in a `const` function, which also makes your `map` `const`. Either way, you can't have a non-`const` operator on a `const` container.

EDIT: Am I the only one who prefers to use explicit types over `auto`?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue, compiled and got something similar with the list as well added const_iterator and now it works. I didn't know about the const_iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the new C++11 `auto` keyword

```
for (auto it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); it++)
{
   cout << it->first << ":";
   for (auto lit = it->second.begin(); lit  != it->second.end(); lit++)
      cout << " " << intToStr(*lit);
   cout << "\n";
}
```

If you still get errors, you have defined inconsistent types.

Comment: Interesting I never heard or read about auto before. Need to read about it and learn. Thanks.

Comment: @LF4 If you use Visual C++ 2010 or higher, or gcc 4.4 or higher, it should compile.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.4.6, have any suggested sites to read about auto? I'm trying to find it on cplusplus.com but it's pulling up a lot of functions of each class (which makes sense if they implement it).

Comment: @LF4 http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the new C++11 [range-based for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop):

```
for(auto& pair : words) {
  std::cout << pair.first << ":";
  for(auto& i : pair.second) {
    std::cout << " " << intToStr(i);
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: God so much cleaner.... I haven't used C++ in over a decade though, what's with the `auto &`? I thought `auto` deduced the full type down to the reference.

Comment: `auto i` create a local initialized to the values of the items in the range. `auto& i` creates a reference bound to the items in the range. If you want to avoid copies, or if you want to modify the items, you have to do `auto&`.

Comment: Hm I see. I guess C#'s `var` keyword is equivalent to `auto &` then.

Comment: Wow a foreach in c++ that is great. I tried implementing it but got the error, "expected initializer before ‘:’ token". This is implemented in a class function and words is a protected map and not in the function itself, if that matters.

Comment: @LF4 - You mentioned that you use g++4.4.6. It looks like your g++ is too old for this feature. It is in the C++11 standard, and it [was implemented in G++ 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I didn't know how to tell if the compiler was C++11 compliant. Still that's great to know about. I'll use that in the future when I can.